# How to write a NotMapped entity in Laravel Model?

Tags: php, laravel-5, model, eloquent

I am novice in `laravel`, therefor my question may be odd to someone. Well, my question is how can I write a entity in Laravel `Model` class which will not be created any field in database after my migration. For example

```
class JobseekerModel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table='dbl_jobseekers';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    protected $fillable=[
        'FirstName',
        'MiddleName',
        'LastName',
        'Dob',
        'Education',
        'DesireField',
        'Skill',
        'SpecialSkill',
        'Experience',
        'Location',
        'HomeAddress',
        'Salary',
        'Comenteries',
        'Resume'
    ];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

This is my Model, now I want to add another property named 'PagedListSize' in my Model, however I don't like to create it as a database column. So how do I do this?

For example I am acquainted to use `NotMapped` property in `.Net Framework`, which is written like

```
[NotMapped]
public int PagedListSize {set; get;}
```

So, how do I able to do this. Is there any way to do this in laravel? i am working on `Laravel 5.4`

Comment: Can you be more specific. Do you need fieald that should be calculated? Or you need simple property of a class?

Comment: Well, I need the simple property of a class, which don't create the column in database. However I will able to pass the data from `Controller` to `view` and `view` to `Controller`. I will just use this property in case of my some calculation purposes. nothing else.

Comment: @lazycoder in your question, where did you state that you need the properties to be serialized? Because the only difference that the accepted answer has with mine, it's that it explains how the properties can be serialized when converting the class to json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this in Laravel indeed is through [custom Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators). In addition, mutators can be configured to be displayed in the json or array output dump of the model. e.g. for `PagedListSize` we could have:

```
public functionGetPagedListSizeAttribute()
{
    return #some evaluation;
}

protected $appends = array('pagedListSize');
```

This way, `pagedListSize` will not only be available directly as a field but also be available whenever the model is [serialized](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization) as Json or Array.

Answer (score 5):

You can create custom [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators) to have that kind of custom properties wihout mapping them to database fields in Laravel.

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
    }

    public function setFullNameAttribute($value)
    {
        list($this->first_name, $this->last_name) = explode(' ', $value);
    }
}
```

and then you can use it like this after you initialize the model:

```
$tag->full_name = "Christos Lytras";
echo $tag->first_name; // prints "Christos"
echo $tag->last_name; // prints "Lytras"
```

Here is a tinker screenshot:

[image: Artisan Tinker Example]

Answer (score 2):

You can add protected properties to Laravel Model, it's fine as long as they do not collide with field-names. Besides, with Laravel, migration are deciding of DB structures, not models, so you do not take the risk to create fields automatically (actually, default models works with no properties out of the box).

EDIT : Example from the default package User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
    * You can add some properties here
    * will require getter and/or setters
    * does not need to be fillable
    */
    protected $someLogicalProperty;

}
```

The actual db structure is defined in the migration (2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php) :

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

As you can see, timestamps and token are not even listed in the user model. All the fillable when defined will be setable as public property on the user object (`$user->name = 'Bob';`, but you can also pass it as argument to the create()/save() inherited methods). Entities are not directly accessed in Laravel, but there are here and can be further specified if needed.